# SQL - Pivot Data/Combine Values

Tags: sql

I have the following table in SQL

[image]

I would like to create a new table that combines the values of FemaleID and MaleID into one column FemaleMale, while bringing in the corresponding columns as well.

Here would be the expected final output.

[image]

```
SELECT FemaleID AS FemaleMale, Stage, Season 
FROM table
UNION 
SELECT MaleID as FemaleMale, Stage, Season
FROM table
```

I tried this code above, but the values in Stage then contain Season values and vice  versa.

Comment: Then you must have miss-aligned your columns, your query looks correct. Without sample data to use it's untestable though. Perhaps you also want something called PersonId?

Comment: paste your actual output

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the error in which you run - with your queries, the columns turn out right - but the order becomes pretty much a mess:

| FemaleMale | Stage | Season |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | TC1 | Summer |
| 123 | TC1 | Summer |
| 444 | TC2 | Summer |
| 123 | TC1 | Spring |
| 123 | TC2 | Summer |
| 789 | TC1 | Spring |

And that is to be expected. Relational tables are *not* ordered. What you give as input will by no means be guaranteed to appear in the same order as you entered them, in a subsequent query. I therefore added two ordering criterions to keep control of the result:

- a new column `seq`, a sequence number for each row.
- an in-line table with two rows, 1 (for the females) and 2 (for the males), as you wish the females to appear before.

And then I `CROSS JOIN`ed the input table and the in-line table together, projected the male/female id depending on the value of `i` for the currently joined row, and ordered by `seq` and `i`.

```
WITH
-- your input - but enriched by a sorting criterion
indata(seq,femaleid,maleid,stage,season) AS (
            SELECT 1,123,789,'TC1','Spring'
  UNION ALL SELECT 2,123,444,'TC2','Summer'
  UNION ALL SELECT 3,123,111,'TC1','Summer'
)
,
i(i) AS (
            SELECT 1
  UNION ALL SELECT 2
)
SELECT
  CASE i
    WHEN 1 THEN femaleid
    WHEN 2 THEN maleid
    ELSE NULL
  END AS femalemale
, stage
, season
FROM indata CROSS JOIN i
ORDER BY seq,i;
```

| femalemale | stage | season |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | TC1 | Spring |
| 789 | TC1 | Spring |
| 123 | TC2 | Summer |
| 444 | TC2 | Summer |
| 123 | TC1 | Summer |
| 111 | TC1 | Summer |

Oh - and I call this operation - verticalising - un-pivot.

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT FemaleID AS FemaleMale, Stage, Season 
FROM table
UNION 
SELECT MaleID as FemaleMale, Stage, Season
FROM table
) ORDER BY Stage, Season
```